# Socket.io Handshake fails on site but not on localhost

Tags: socket.io

Socket.io handshake fails on my site but not on localhost.
I had to provide a custom handshake because socket.io was unable to find my query parameter.

Here is my declaration in socket.service.js:

```
var ioSocket = io('https://my-site.rhcloud.com//?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1414328625757-0&
token=' + Auth.getToken(), {

});
```

and how I catch it on server side :

```
socketio.use(function(socket, next) {
      request.get('https://my-site.rhcloud.com/api/users/chan', {qs:{access_token:socket.handshake.query.token}}, function(err, me) {
          if (err||!me.body|| me.body=='Unauthorized') {
              if (!me) console.log('!me');
              if (err) console.log(err);
              next(err);
          }
          else {
              // perfoming operations
              next();
          }
      });
  });
```

Here is the message I get:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-site.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket&t=…YwMX0.1F6ebfNxzoDPYffXGapGMzLFPJd-mfN0EexqZzXXo7A&sid=z0Jmrbgb7OS0nbqxAAAG' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

I'm really lost here, and digged a lot into Google without any success.
Any help would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a lot of search, I realized the problem came from Openshift. You have to specify the port sockets are going to use. See this article: https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/

So, I just had to write:

```
var ioSocket = io('http://my-site.rhcloud.com:8000, {

});
```

Comment: Where did you have to write this? I am having the same problem in Windows running it on IIS 8. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: I mean I am using NodeBB forum software so I am not really declaring the socket anywhere. I would like to fix it without a need to go too much into source.

Comment: @OndrejTokar Sorry for the delay, didn't see your comment. I declared this on client side, in the Angular service responsible for socket declaration

Answer (score 8):

Nginx proxy solves the issue with the following config:

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

Original solution [here](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/). It works great for me (Ubuntu 14.4 + Plesk 12.5).

Answer (score 4):

I deployed my node/express server to Azure and I got the folowing error

**websocket.js:100 WebSocket connection to 'ws://mywebsitename.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=ssEHs-OWxI6mcChyAAAB' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503**

, I fixed my issue by enable WebSocket in Azure console as shown below 
[image: enable web sockets in Azure]