# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400 on free OpenShift MEAN stack server

Tags: socket.io, openshift, mean-stack, handshake

I'm working on twitter search web app http://twitter.batak.tk/ and locally everything works fine but when I deploy it on OPENSHIFT MEAN stack server (free) I'm getting this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://nodejs-igrica.rhcloud.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=Wtvf6VI-9QqTvICUAAAI' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

twitter.batak.tk is just an alias to nodejs-igrica.rhcloud.com.

This is my socket service code:

```
app.
factory('SearchService', ['socketFactory', function(socketFactory) {
        var myIoSocket = io.connect('http://nodejs-igrica.rhcloud.com/:8000', {'forceNew':true });

        mySocket = socketFactory({
            ioSocket: myIoSocket
        });

        return mySocket;
}]);
```

and this is a server.js:
https://github.com/isBatak/twitter_search_web_app/blob/master/server.js

I'm stuck with this...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io Handshake fails on site but not on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993447/socket-io-handshake-fails-on-site-but-not-on-localhost)

Answer (score 4):

The problem came from Openshift. You have to specify the port sockets are going to use. Just had to write:

```
var ioSocket = io.connect('http://my-site.rhcloud.com:8000');
```

You must use port 8000.
Source: [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26993447/socket-io-handshake-fails-on-site-but-not-on-localhost), same problem like you

**Extra**

You should use a subdomain to access your openshift app. Use for example:

```
http://node.yourdomain.com:8000
```

Instead of

```
http://my-site.rhcloud.com:8000
```

Remember, you have to set up an alias for your gear in OpenShift in order to be correctly redirected.

Comment: With a bit more rep, [you will be able to flag duplicate questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Until then, posting links as answers is not really ideal, and they will generally be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Hi did you try your server using the websocket.org echo service?